# MySQL better approach to check duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For My `user` table in MySQL, before entering new userid & avoid duplicate userid, I check if similar Id exist. To me there are 3 approach :

1. Query for new userid (`SELECT ...`) and check `0` row returned. If row exists then request for new userid, else (`INSERT...`)
2. Make `userid` column `UNIQUE` in `user` table and directly `INSERT...` if `0` rows affected then request new userid
3. Make `userid` column `UNIQUE` in `user` table and directly `INSERT...` if `mysqli_errno ($link)==1062` then request new userid

I presently use 1st method but it results in 2 query and intend to switch to second method. I found 3rd approach in a book which confused me !

My question is

- Is 2nd approach better for duplicate entry prevention ?
- Are 2nd & 3rd aprroach same or different ?
- Is there still any better approach to prevent duplicate entry with minimum DB Query ?

Comment: I just want to make sure that you are aware of AUTO_INCREMENT which will automatically assign an ID to a row that you insert that is unique. - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Thanks but I know about `AI`, just improving on Mysql and correcting ages old code I wrote as novice. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my answers:

1. Is 2nd approach better for duplicate entry prevention?

   yes, in my opinion second approach is better, if you know that `userid` is going to be always unique, you should make it a `unique` field, `MySQL` will automatically handle it.
2. Are 2nd & 3rd approach same or different?

   I think both are same and `MySQL` throws error in these cases.
3. Is there still any better approach to prevent duplicate entry with minimum DB Query?

   You can put `UNIQUE INDEX` on this column, that will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

1) Duplication should  be handled by your database by make `unique` fields.

2) When you try to insert the same data in a unique field, it'll give you an error. The error would be like -

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'UNIQUE'
```

3) Hence to avoid such error, you have to check through your code that is the data already available in the table.

**CONCLUSION:**

You have to use 1 & 2 approaches parallely to be 100% ensure that, no duplicate entries would exist in your table.